# I can't install elementary and i'm stuck in an endless loop

Tags: boot, acer

When trying to install elementary ( first time) it boots, i go through the entire installation process, and then, when i restart the computer, it tells me to "remove installation media and press enter". When i do so, the computer restarts and then tells me " No bootable device found ". I don't know why it does that, it seems like it hasn't installed it. I tried doing that without removing the usb drive but it just goes through the installation process again. I'm on a acer inspire btw

Comment: have you tried modifying the boot order in the BIOS (i.e make the HDD boot before the USB drive)?

Comment: Maybe you trying the UEFI mode and your hardware is not supported, I have that problem on Dell XPS.

Answer (score 0):

If it is it a dual boot probably /boot/efi partition is not created. I recommend to manually create partitions 
/ - 50 - 100 GB
/boot/efi - 1024 - 2048 MB
/home - 50 - 100 GB
/var - 25 - 50 GB
/swap - 8192 MB
Other partitions can be created but it is not necessary.